# jQuery : Dropzone.js not working inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

In my bootstrap modal I have a div panel inside of that is my form of dropzone, in every time I tried to click the modal nothing is showing. It's working properly if outside of the modal. I also try the `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;` not working either.

```
<div class="panel-body" id="id_dropzone">
   <form action="UploadImages"
                          class="dropzone"
                          id="my-awesome-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    </form>
</div>
```

The JS

```
$(document).on('click','#add_newContestant', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#id_dropzone", { url: 'UploadImages'});
});
```

Comment: you need to trigger dropzone on bootstrap modals `shown` event. check the modal documentation, it shows different events like `shown.bs.modal`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, here i didn't use `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;`

```
// "myAwesomeDropzone" is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 2, // MB
  accept: function(file, done) {
    if (file.name == "anything.jpg") {
      done("false");
    }
    else { done(); }
  }
};
```

and

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 10,
        url: 'UploadImages',
        previewsContainer: "#dropzone-previews",
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 5,
        maxFiles: 20,
        init: function () {
            var cd;
            this.on("success", function (file, response) {
                $('.dz-progress').hide();
                $('.dz-size').hide();
                $('.dz-error-mark').hide();
                console.log(response);
                console.log(file);
                cd = response;
            });

              .......
```

Please check this fiddle [Dropzone in Modal](http://jsfiddle.net/minhaj_mimo/jh63ueha/) . I think this will help you